# How to use dynamic file paths for responses with Wiremock.Net?

Tags: .net, wiremock

I have a question about the current capabilities of templating.

I'd like to retrieve responses from files using WireMock.Net, and for that I am using static mappings with "BodyAsFile" attribute.

Example:

```
{
    "Request": {
        "Path": {
            "Matchers": [
                {
                    "Name": "WildcardMatcher",
                    "Pattern": "/bodyasfilexmltest",
                    "IgnoreCase": false
                }
            ]
        },
        "Methods": [
            "get"
        ]
    },
  "Response": {
    "StatusCode": 200,
    "Headers": { "Content-Type": "application/xml" },
    "BodyAsFile": "c:\\temp-wiremock\\__admin\\mappings\\MyXmlResponse.xml",
    "UseTransformer": false
  }
}
```

But I'd like to vary the response directory based on the request attributes, pretty much as Handlebars templates do.

Example (MyUniqueNumber would be the name of each folder):

```
"BodyAsFile": "c:\\temp-wiremock\\__admin\\mappings\\_{{request.query.MyUniqueNumber}}_\\MyXmlResponse.xml",
```

In this example the variable is in the Path, but it could be appended to the file name as well.

I did test it and it seems the library tries to load the file from disk when loaded and not per request, so it cannot find the invalid path "c:\temp-wiremock__admin\mappings{{request.query.MyUniqueNumber}}\MyXmlResponse.xml".

Is this scenario currently supported (maybe in a different way)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is solved in [WireMock.Net version 1.0.15](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WireMock.Net/1.0.15)